# Can you add a constant value to a length macro?

Tags: calculations, lengths

I have a box that's the full width of the page.  I would like to offset it back into the margin a little, but when I do that it no longer reaches the edge of the page.  Is it possible to keep using a macro like `\textwidth` but add a constant value onto it?

```
\hspace{-5mm} % Go back into the margin a bit
\colorbox[gray]{0.85}{
  \parbox{\textwidth}{  % Need \textwidth + 5mm to end up in the same place
    Hello
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add

```
  \usepackage{calc}
```

then you can go

```
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth + 5mm}
```

Comment: Works great and very clean syntax - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

With a current pdftex you can do

```
\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth+5mm\relax}{...}
```

`\parbox` doesn't know the `[l]` option you used.

Comment: That works nicely if the calc package is unavailable, thanks.  I'm not sure where the `[l]` came from in that case but you're right, it shouldn't be there.